# How to change labels of cureves in plotly.express.bar

Tags: plotly-python

I have the following figure:
[image]
I need to change the labels in legend.

I read the documentation for [plotly.express.bar](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar) and I think `color_discrete_map` is relevant, but I don't know how to apply it.
As you see there is 6 colors in the figure and I want to assign a text to each color.

```py
def update_figure_profits(df0,
                          label,
                          xlabel=None,
                          ylabel=None,
                          title=None,
                          percent_fmt=False):
    c = ['#636EFA', '#EF553B', '#00CC96',
         '#AB63FA', '#FFA15A', '#19D3F3'] * 3
    df = df0[[label, 'name']].copy()
    fig = px.bar(df,
                 x=range(len(df)),
                 y=label,
                 color=c,
                 )
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(
        tickmode='array',
        tickvals=list(range(18)),
        ticktext=['', '', 'کامل', '', '', ''] + ['', '', 'متغیر', '', '', ''] + 
        ['', '', 'فرامتغیر', '', '', '']
    )
    )
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_title=xlabel,
                      yaxis_title=ylabel,)
    fig.update_layout(title_text=title, title_x=0.5)
    return fig
```

and the data look like this:

```sh
      id         name          cost       sell        profit  profit_margin  efficiency_on_fixed_asset   costing_type
0   1000     سنگِ آهن  4.794900e+06   13759200  8.964300e+06       0.651513                   0.664022           full
1   2000     کنسانتره  1.155342e+07   22464000  1.091058e+07       0.485692                   0.808191           full
2   3000        گندله  1.470069e+07   32993999  1.829331e+07       0.554443                   1.355060           full
3   4000  آهنِ اسفنجی  2.669225e+07   70200000  4.350775e+07       0.619768                   3.222796           full
4   5000          شمش  5.577847e+07  140400000  8.462153e+07       0.602717                   6.268262           full
5   6000    نوردِ گرم  6.269642e+07  155984400  9.328798e+07       0.598060                   6.910220           full
6   1000     سنگِ آهن  3.863700e+06   13759200  9.895500e+06       0.719192                   0.733000       variable
7   2000     کنسانتره  8.976960e+06   22464000  1.348704e+07       0.600385                   0.999040       variable
8   3000        گندله  1.097908e+07   32993999  2.201492e+07       0.667240                   1.630735       variable
9   4000  آهنِ اسفنجی  1.932668e+07   70200000  5.087332e+07       0.724691                   3.768394       variable
10  5000          شمش  3.871631e+07  140400000  1.016837e+08       0.724243                   7.532125       variable
11  6000    نوردِ گرم  4.260937e+07  155984400  1.133750e+08       0.726836                   8.398151       variable
12  1000     سنگِ آهن  1.123200e+06   13759200  1.263600e+07       0.918367                   0.936000  supervariable
13  2000     کنسانتره  4.164883e+06   22464000  1.829912e+07       0.814597                   1.355490  supervariable
14  3000        گندله  5.850284e+06   32993999  2.714371e+07       0.822686                   2.010646  supervariable
15  4000  آهنِ اسفنجی  1.052448e+07   70200000  5.967552e+07       0.850079                   4.420409  supervariable
16  5000          شمش  2.459279e+07  140400000  1.158072e+08       0.824838                   8.578312  supervariable
17  6000    نوردِ گرم  2.535339e+07  155984400  1.306310e+08       0.837462                   9.676371  supervariable
```

Thanks for any guide.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i didn't read the whole code but what you've done in 2nd line is wrong, the color argument in bar function doesn't mean the colors themselves as you've written,
see the definition from plotly website

> color (str or int or Series or array-like) – Either a name of a column in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from this column or array_like are used to assign color to marks

so in your case, color would be "costing_type" or "name"